# Can I add a tabbed widget to my Markdown page?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I would like to add a tabbed widget to toggle between different views of similar content. Something like the way [Xamarin's documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debugging/debug-on-device/) lets users toggle between Visual Studio for Windows and Visual Studio for Mac:

[image: Windows / Mac content toggle]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Markdown doesn't support anything like that. After all, [it was designed for writing prose](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> The idea for Markdown is to make it easy to read, write, and edit prose. HTML is a *publishing* format; Markdown is a *writing* format. Thus, Markdown’s formatting syntax only addresses issues that can be conveyed in plain text.

[GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/#GitHub-flavored-markdown) adds support for some features not included in the original Markdown specification (e.g. tables, strikethrough, fenced code blocks with syntax highlighting) but nothing like a tabbed interface.

I'm not aware of any Markdown implementations that offer something like this.

The best alternative using pure Markdown would be to simply include headers to separate your OS-specific instructions, e.g.

```
# Step 1

## Windows

...

## macOS

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found [Tabbed](https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/tabbed/) - an Python-Markdown
extension that supports tabs with following syntax:

```
=== "Tab 1"
    Tab 1 content

=== "Tab 2"
    Tab 2 content
```

But that's about it. No implementations for any other Markdown renderers.