# How to create code snippet with tabs in Github?

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

How to create code snippet with tabs in Github, something like this::

[image]

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/49104108/354577

Answer (score 4):

GitHub pages or [GFM (GitHub Flavored Markdown)](https://github.github.com/gfm/) themselves does not have a feature for that kind of snippet code presentation.

For GitHub pages, you would need to upload an HTML page, with the right CSS, n order to achive that kind of presentation.